# how to communicate from javascript to java application

Tags: java, javascript

I am storing data in a cloud in some format. This cloud is accessible through https URL. There are java and java script API's to communicate with cloud. I want to provide basic CRUD functionality. I have a textarea in which I am receiving input from the user. I have a java library for parsing the SQL queries. How do I communicate from javascript in my HTML page to java application where it performs computation on data on cloud and communicates with cloud.

I am a newbie at web development. I appreciate any help!!

Comment: I think you will need to clarify a bit more the architecture you have. You are saying your data is in 'the cloud' through some HTTPS URL, and at the same time you are saying you have some server-side Java which is doing SQL queries. Also indicate what APIs and technology stack you are using (are you using Java Servlets? Tomcat? any libraries? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Google ajax.......

With Ajax, web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. Data can be retrieved using the XMLHttpRequest object. Despite the name, the use of XML is not required (JSON is often used instead), and the requests do not need to be asynchronous.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/21/complete-ajax-tutorial/

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html

http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/